# Google Analytics virtual pageview tracking code inconsistently records pageviews

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, analytics

I'm using a Javascript image gallery in which the next/prev transitions record browser history, or at least fake it by changing the URL and back-button behavior.

So if the gallery is at:

`http:://example.com/gallery/`

The "next" button takes you to the next photo, which the JavaScript converts the URL to:

`http://example.com/gallery/#/1`

In the gallery's next/prev `onclick` event, I have something like this:

```
var loc =  window.location; 
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', loc]);
```

So in the Google Analytics dashboard, the default overview (current month), the gallery shows the expected uptick in pageviews versus visitors...it's sizable, about 200%. However, when we limit the timeframe to a single day (the first day the gallery went live, which is also the day that it gets the majority of its traffic), its *pageviews* go down to the typical number of pageviews per article we've had on our site.

I don't know if it's a fluke in GA's aggregation, i.e. the month-tally is more up to date than the individual day tallies. However, I'm also wondering if the funky URL structure that I'm sending it via `_trackPageview` is not kosher. That is, the `gallery/#/number` structure, the hashtag in particular, does not result in a proper cookie operation.

But I may just be using the GA code (the async version) improperly. So not sure which of the scenarios I'm in right now.

Answer (score 0):

If the content is loaded via AJAX, it is better to track using [virtual pageviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032351/analytics-on-a-bootstrap-modal-with-pageview-and-time-related-metrics/) or events.

But, if you want to send the location like you do now, I think sending `window.location` is a wrong way to do it. This is because `window.location` is an object, and not a string. You must send `window.location.href` which is a string which contains the full URL. But that will contain the protocol (http:// or https://) the domain name (subdomain.domain.com/) as well, so you have to work with it. Or, if you have no need for the query strings, which both Google Analytics (GA) and Universal Analytics (UA) will not track by default, send it as `window.location.pathname`, which will be the relative path that GA/UA expects.

Hope that helps. :)

I suggest you migrate to UA as soon as possible. GA will be retired soon.