# Is there a way in JavaScript to test that a XMLHttpRequest was made to a certain URL?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I know how to view network traffic in the browser's dev tools and to have XMLHttpRequests displayed in the console, but is there a window property that displays all the network traffic?

Comment: you can write an ajaxPrefilter if you can(using jquery) and log everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/).

And if you're without it, you could just *extend* `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open` to fire your custom event.

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
  // The ajaxSend() method is a callback which is fired
      every time a jQuery AJAX call is completed. 
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ 
    if (iswantedurl(settings.url.pathname)){
        // ga('send','pageview',settings.url.pathname);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

origin code from [How to extend google analytics to track AJAX etc (as per H5BP docs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033205/how-to-extend-google-analytics-to-track-ajax-etc-as-per-h5bp-docs)

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript:

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, password) {
        // Add my code to record all the requests
    if (!window.XMLLog) window.XMLLog = [];
    window.XMLLog.push(this);

        // Don't break the original JS
    return this.xhr.open(method, url, async, user, password);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ 
  if (!window.XMLLog) window.XMLLog = [];
  window.XMLLog.push({event:event,xhr:xhr,settings:settings});
});
```