# google analytics count of visitor in a page ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-analytics

I want to put [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics) in my project to know how many people is visiting the pages of my site, it seems easy to put into the site since you just copy a code and paste in every page you want to have the analytics.

My question is this, in my site i am using ajax and the only page i have is the index page the rest is loaded in the index as div. Will it be counted even if i use ajax i mean when they visit a certain page will the number of visit be counted?

Answer (score 2):

For newer version of google analytic please use below code for ajax tracking. Paste this code into the new file and keep that file into the app/assets/javascritps/analytics.js. Also include it into the application.js

```
   (function ($) {
     $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){
        if (typeof ga !== "undefined" && ga !== null) {
         ga('send', {
           'hitType': 'pageview',
           'page': settings.url
         });
        }
     });
    })(jQuery);
```

code for add dynamically into the ajax call

```
   $.ajax({
     type : 'get',
     url : url,
     data : {"curr_code": currency}
    }).done(function(){
         ga('send', {‘hitType': 'pageview', 'page':  url });
    });
```

For more details please refer to this link http://tarungarg402.blogspot.in/2015/01/google-analyicts-wth-rails.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to count an Ajax call.

**JQuery Ajax Example:**

This code will automatically log all jQuery AJAX requests in your application, including those using `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, or `$.post()` (and `.load()` too).

> This will also work for any jQuery plugins using AJAX requests (e.g.
>   lightbox plugins, etc.), as well as for all Rails 3 remote links and
>   forms (provided we're using the jQuery UJS driver).

In the page layout or in an included js file, you add the following JavaScript:

Updated to make sure **_gaq** is defined and loaded in page.

```
(function ($) {

  // Log all jQuery AJAX requests to Google Analytics
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ 
    if (typeof _gaq !== "undefined" && _gaq !== null) {
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', settings.url]);
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

If you're using this in a Rails 3 app, you can put this in your **application.js**.

**Note:-** This assumes you are using the **Asynchronous version of Google Analytics**. If you are using the **older** synchronous Analytics code snippet, you just need to replace the **_gaq** with the older **pagetracker** syntax:

```
(function ($) {

  // Log all jQuery AJAX requests to Google Analytics
  $(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings){ 
    if (typeof pageTracker !== "undefined" && pageTracker !== null) {
      pageTracker._trackPageview(settings.url);
    }
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Also, notice you don't need to put the JavaScript inside the **$(document).ready()** event. This is because you're only binding a function to a callback, to be run later when the callback is triggered; you're not actually executing any code on the DOM yet.

**How it works:**
jQuery fires off several local and global AJAX callbacks whenever it executes an AJAX request. The local callbacks fire on the specific element that triggered the AJAX request (i.e. the link or form), while the global callbacks are broadcast to all elements in the DOM, including the root node, document.

So, you are simply binding a function to the root node, on the ajaxSend callback. That function then uses the Google Analytics function for manually logging a page request for the AJAX URL.

On a related note, if you want to make a specific AJAX request stealthy, and not broadcast its global AJAX callbacks to other DOM elements, you can set global to false. This will also cause our Analytics tracking to be skipped for this request.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/like-a-ninja',
  global: false
});
```

([source](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/track-jquery-ajax-requests-in-google-analytics/))

**I strongly recommend to read followings as well.**

Below one has a **very detailed answer** and **working code example**.
[How to extend google analytics to track AJAX etc (as per H5BP docs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033205/how-to-extend-google-analytics-to-track-ajax-etc-as-per-h5bp-docs)

**Track AJAX Link Clicks Using Google Analytics** by David Walsh: http://davidwalsh.name/ajax-analytics

**HTML5 boilerplate : Track jQuery AJAX requests in Google Analytics** 
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/v4.3.0/doc/extend.md

An article by **@JangoSteve** explains [how to track jQuery AJAX requests in Google Analytics](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/track-jquery-ajax-requests-in-google-analytics/).

Hope it will help you in it.

Answer (score 0):

We have site on Ruby on Rails 4.1 and using turbolinks, which allows to browse website without reloading each page. We had issue with GA because of that.

So we are attaching event listener

```
document.addEventListener("page:change", (function() {
  return GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview();
}


  GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview = function(url) {
    if (url) {
      window._gaq.push(["_trackPageview", url]);
    } else {
      window._gaq.push(["_trackPageview"]);
    }
    return window._gaq.push(["_trackPageLoadTime"]);  
  };
```

Original tutorial is here [Google Analytics with Turbolinks](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html%20Google%20Analytics%20with%20Turbolinks) and it its posted in CoffeeScript but you can convert it using [Js2Coffee page](http://js2coffee.org)

Answer (score -2):

Every time when you load page with ajax you can tell GA to count it as a separate URL. Example of the code that should be run at the end of ajax update of the page:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/some-page']);
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide + https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._trackPageview

> _trackPageview(opt_pageURL)
>
> Main logic for GATC (Google Analytic Tracker Code). If linker functionalities are enabled, it   attempts to
>   extract cookie values from the URL. Otherwise, it tries to extract
>   cookie values from document.cookie. It also updates or creates cookies
>   as necessary, then writes them back to the document object. Gathers
>   all the appropriate metrics to send to the UCFE (Urchin Collector
>   Front-end).
>
> String opt_pageURL
>
> Optional parameter to indicate what
>   page URL to track metrics under. When using this option, use a
>   beginning slash (/) to indicate the page URL.