# Conflict? Bootstrap modal with Google Analytics onclick

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics, modal-dialog

I have a page that has several bootstrap modals. I'm trying to track clicks as virtual page views in google analytics on these modals with:

```
onClick="ga(‘send’, ‘pageview’, ‘Translation - <?php echo $language_name_in_english; ?> - <?php wp_title(''); ?>’);’);"
```

However, its not tracking. I've replaced the `onclick` code with a simple `alert` and it still won't work. It seems like there is a conflict between the two. However, I've seen these work in concert before.

So I guess my question is: 
What could cause a conflict between a bootstrap modal and an onclick? Or is there a better way to do this?

The answer in this link is exactly what I'm trying to do.
[Analytics on a bootstrap modal with pageview and time related metrics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032351/analytics-on-a-bootstrap-modal-with-pageview-and-time-related-metrics)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can i give you an advice? Bootstrap Modals dispatches events related to its use. You could track the event of loaded or shown instead of doing that on the click button. You will even be able to track N Modals with just one snippet of code. See: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events

Comment: @DiegoZoracKy is right.

Answer (score 0):

If that is an exact copy of the code on your site, then you may need to change the smart quotes to straight quotes. There is also a bracket mismatch at the end:

```
onClick="ga('send', 'pageview', 'Translation - <?php echo $language_name_in_english; ?> - <?php wp_title(''); ?>');"
```