# Track Bootstrap3 modal with google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-analytics

I have a landing page built with bootstrap3 and a modals on the page. 
I want to track the how many people actually go to the subscribe modal. From some other post and the bootstrap docs I figured this out. But I cant find any track from that in my analytics.

`$('#signup_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
   _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/subscibe_modal']);
})`

Any Ideas or suggestions?

regards
denym_

Comment: is your jQuery firing? what if you toss an alert in there to see if it's even getting to the GA push.

Comment: Yes it fired. I put an `alert('moep')` after the push and it got fired on modal opening. And am I right with the conclusion that in my analytics a page should be listed that is called `/subscibe_modal`?

Comment: Great! This may be a dumb question, but are people actually clicking on it in the last 24 hours? If not that may be your issue. Otherwise double check your [GA tag](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide). Also do you have to use the GA tag within the jQuery, or can you attach it to a button the user clicks?

Comment: Yes the button was clicked :) Tracking the button click was my next idea to try. But since there are like 3 or 4 buttons leading to this modal its kinda... you know. And I would prefer to have it as tracked pageview than an event.

Comment: I have a landing page that uses BS3 and the BS3 navbar. I found that using this - ga('send', 'pageview', '/index.html#pricing'); - worked for me. I think i grabbed this from [GA single app page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications) .

Comment: @Geoffrey This just counts towards overall pageview if the #pricing gets clicked. I want a specific counting just on the modal.

Comment: Just for information. I had to use `ga('send', 'pageview', '/yada');` I took the wrong it is from the classic analytics. Works fine now, also for the opening modal.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032351/analytics-on-a-bootstrap-modal-with-pageview-and-time-related-metrics

Comment: [try this link I found solution here to a similar problem. Hope this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032351/analytics-on-a-bootstrap-modal-with-pageview-and-time-related-metrics)